# How to multiply a number by itself X times?

Tags: php, math

There is some operator that works like this: 5^2 = 5*5 = 25. I tried using 5^2 which didn't work. I tried searching for any names of this ^ operator to no avail. How can I do a calculation like this in PHP?

Thanks!

Comment: `^` is the bitwise XOR operator in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: You didn't think to google [php to the power](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+to+the+power)? Or [php base exponent](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+base+exponent)?

Comment: `^` is bitwise XOR in just about everything.

Answer (score 11):

You can use [pow](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php) function.

So, your example would be:

```
echo pow(5, 2);  // will echo 25
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use POW php function. Code:

```
pow(5,2)
```

Answer (score 3):

`pow($base, $exp)`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Answer (score 3):

Have people *really* forgotten the **Law of Logarithms** from their junior-high-school algebra this quickly?

Even  if you don’t remember the short-cut `pow` function, you should still remember how to use logarithms!

```
 echo exp(log(5) + log(10));  # 5*10
 echo exp(log(5)     * 2);    # 5**2
 echo exp(log(7)     * 7);    # 7**7
 echo exp(log(2.5) * 3.75);   # 2.5**3.75
 echo exp(log(49)  * 0.5);    # sqrt 49
 echo exp(log(125) * (1/3))   # cube root of 125
 echo exp(log(81)  * 0.25);   # 4th root of 81
```

Somewhere out there, there’s a sliderule calling out your name.

Answer (score 2):

There's a `pow` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php).

E.g.:

```
pow(2, 8)
```

Is equal to 2^8 ...